# Using Stored Procedure for only delete in Entity

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, stored-procedures, asp.net-web-api

Here's my stored proc I want to use in my DB:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.usp_DeleteExample 
@ExampleID int, @LoggedInUserID int, @SessionID int, @AppID smallint
as

Declare @ExampleName varchar(255)

Set @ExampleName = (Select VehicleName from Example where ExampleID = @ExampleID)

Delete from ExampleToGeofence where ExampleID = @ExampleID;


exec usp_DeleteExampleHistoryData @ExampleID;
Delete From Example where ExampleID = @ExampleID;

Insert into UserActionHistory(ActionID, UserID, SessionID, ItemID, OldValue, ApplicationID, EventUTCDate)
Values (203, @LoggedInUserID, @SessionID, @ExampleID, @ExampleName, @AppID, getutcdate());
```

Here's my code where I'm trying to use it:

```
public Example Delete(Example example)
{
    db.Examples.SqlQuery("usp_DeleteExample @ExampleID", 
        new SqlParameter("ExampleID", example.ExampleID)
    );
    db.SaveChanges();

    return example;
}
```

Yet, when I call this through my WebAPI, nothing gets deleted.

What am I doing wrong here? Please let me know if you need more information.

Thank you.

Edit:

ModelBuilder configuration I just added:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Example>()
    .MapToStoredProcedures(e =>
        e.Delete(v => v.HasName("usp_DeleteExample")));
```

Comment: Have you imported the stored procedure via the model browser?  This is a query run against what appears to be a table called Examples.  Seems a little weird to me...

Comment: do you get any errors? You seem to be passing only one parameter where the procedure clearly needs more. Also, run a trace on the DB to see if the PROC is really being called

Comment: Thank you. There's an Insert happening at the bottom of the procedure. Not there yet in the build. The Deletes should work without those params, right?

Comment: no because if your proc needs 3 parameters and you pass just one, the call will fail therefore nothing will ahppen

Comment: It's not necessary to call the stored procedure in code if you use `MapToStoredProcedures`. Are you aware of what `MapToStoredProcedures` means and what it does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you should be using [DbContext.Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.database%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)`.ExecuteSqlCommand`.  I'm not aware of any such format `DbContext.TableName.ExecuteSqlCommand`.

```
    db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("usp_DeleteExample @ExampleID, @LoggedInUserID, @SessionID, @AppID ", 
        new SqlParameter("LoggedInUserID", variableName), new SqlParameter("SessionID", variableName),new SqlParameter("AppID ", variableName));
```

Because you are not modifying an entity there's no need to call `SaveChanges()` either.  Personally, I import the SP's in the designer so they are readily available in C#.

Also note that you need to add the other 3 parameters because none of the parameters are [optional](http://weblogs.asp.net/rmclaws/archive/2004/02/18/75381.aspx).

Comment: I commented them out to get the stored proc to work. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

`SqlQuery` is used to *return* entities.  I think you want `ExecuteSQlCommand`:

```
public void Delete(Example example)
{
    db.Examples.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec usp_DeleteExample @ExampleID", 
        new SqlParameter("@ExampleID", example.ExampleID)
    );
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. ExecuteSqlCommand() isn't showing up, even when referenced. I upgraded to Entity 6.0 recently, but I'm still using VS2010. Is it no longer available in E6.0?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's some kind of limitations for the use of stored procedures for CRUD operations.

> You must map insert, update and delete stored procedures to an entity
> if you want to use stored procedure for CUD operations. Mapping only
> one of them is not allowed.

[Source](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/code-first-insert-update-delete-stored-procedure-mapping.aspx#:%7E:text=Entity%20Framework%206%20Code%2DFirst%20provides%20the%20ability%20to%20create,for%20the%20following%20Student%20entity.)

Comment: They probably did that. Either way, the error in the question is nothing but calling a stored procedure with insufficient parameters.

Answer (score -1):

```cs
public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int id)
{
    conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-QRACUST\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LeadManagement;Integrated Security=True";
    conn.Open();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (conn)
    //data get by query
    //using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM EmployeeDetails WHERE EmployeeId=3;", conn))
    //data get by sp
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("EmployeeDetailsDelete", conn))
    using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        da.Fill(dt);
    }
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, dt);
}
```

Comment: Could you indicate how this answers the question and how it complements existing answers? Code-only answers aren't deemed very useful on Stack Overflow.